# spark error:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Size exceeds Integer.MAX_VALUE

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning

I try to compute numbers of negative samples, as following:

```
val numNegatives = dataSet.filter(col("label") < 0.5).count
```

but I got a Size exceeds Integer.MAX_VALUE error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Size exceeds Integer.MAX_VALUE
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map(FileChannelImpl.java:869)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskStore$$anonfun$getBytes$2.apply(DiskStore.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskStore$$anonfun$getBytes$2.apply(DiskStore.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1239)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskStore.getBytes(DiskStore.scala:129)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskStore.getBytes(DiskStore.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doGetLocal(BlockManager.scala:512)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getLocal(BlockManager.scala:427)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.get(BlockManager.scala:636)
    at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:44)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:268)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Some resolvents suggest adding the partition number，so I update the above code as following:

```
val data = dataSet.repartition(5000).cache()
val numNegatives = data.filter(col("label") < 0.5).count
```

But it reports the same error! It confused me several days. Who can help me?
Thanks.

Comment: I think that one column of  your dataset contains numbers that don't fit on an not. How do you get that dataset ?

Comment: I got the data set with spark-hive sql：select id,cast(label as double) label, ... from table.It seems every column should fit each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem hers is the ShuffleRDD block size after it materializes is greater than 2GB. Spark has this [limitation](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6235). You need to change the `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` parameter which is set to 200 be default.

Also you might need to increase the number of partitions that your dataset has. Re partition and save it first then read the new dataset and perform operation.

```
spark.sql("SET spark.sql.shuffle.partitions = 10000")
dataset.repartition(10000).write.parquet("/path/to/hdfs")
val newDataset = spark.read.parquet("/path/to/hdfs")  
newDatase.filter(...).count
```

Alternatively if you want to use Hive Table

```
spark.sql("SET spark.sql.shuffle.partitions = 10000")
dataset.repartition(10000).asveAsTable("newTableName")
val newDataset = spark.table("newTableName")  
newDatase.filter(...).count
```

Comment: i tried like this: val data = dataSet.repartition(5000).cache()
val numNegatives = data.filter(col("label") < 0.5).count, but the error is always here.

Comment: Don't Cache. Please increase the partition.. Make it 10000, save the data on the HDfs or s3 first after repartititon. Then load it and do any operation. Also as I suggested please increase the spark.sql.shuffle.partition to 10000. I have faced this issue numerous times and this has worked for me

Comment: The hdfs file is inserted by hive sql, only one file, so the size of the file is 2.13G. In hive sql can i repartition the hdfs file?

Comment: I have updated the answer with exactly the steps you need to follow to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try repartition before filter:

val numNegatives = dataSet.repartition(1000).filter(col("label") < 0.5).count

Filter executes with original DataSet partitions and repartition the result. You need have smaller partitions for filter.